# How to mimic List<Optional<T>> like behaviour in Spring Data Repo?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to `query` the Database with a `list of Id's` and, in case they don't exist, do some stuff with them.

My plan was to do something like

```
List<Optional<MyObject>> fingById(Set<String> myIds);
```

I understand this wont' work out of the box because I suppose that even if all the id's where present nothing guarantees me that they will be ordered, so if some of them are present I will get some random null optionals around which I won't be able to may to the Id that returned it.

Basically what I need to do in the end is to retrieve these objects, update one field or create them with default value if not present.

Which is the best way of doing this in batch?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why have a `List<Optional<MyObject>>`? If you want the `MyObject` for each `String` ID, isn't a `Map<String,MyObject>` better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the results by their id into `Map<String, Optional<MyObject>>` and then fill in the blanks with `Optional.empty()`.

```
List<MyObject> findByIdIn(Set<String> ids);

default Map<String, Optional<MyObject>> mapByIdIn(Set<String> ids) {
    Map<String, Optional<MyObject>> found = findByIdIn(ids)
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(MyObject::getId, Optional::of));
    ids.stream()
       .filter(id -> !found.containsKey(id))
       .forEach(id -> found.put(id, Optional.empty()));
    return found;
}
```

Comment: I really like that, and I actually learned about this default method stuff which I hadn't seen yet. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, just tried your option and sadly got:

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/sacs] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01797: this operator must be followed by ANY or ALL

Comment: @epsilonmajorquezero try renaming to `findByIdIn`

Comment: Wow, that was fast, just got time to find it by myself :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I don´t think that it is a good idea to use a `List` of `Optional` values. Instead, I recommend to just use the default methods of the repository and query for all existing entities.

```
List<MyObject> findAll();
```

After that, you can iterate through all objects and check for missing ids. To improve performance, i recommend the useage of a `Map`:

```
var objectMap = repository.findAll().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(MyObject::getId, Function::Identity);
```

Then, you can simply check if any of the ids is contained in the map:

```
myIds.stream().filter(objectMap::contains)
    .forEach({
        // do some stuff, present id
    });

myIds.stream().filter((id) -> !myMap.contains(id))
    .forEach({
        // do some stuff, not present id
    });
```

Comment: findAll() is likely to retrieve from a few hundret thousand to some milions of entries while I actually only need to retrieve around 100 of Id's so I'd say that would be quite an overshoot :)

Comment: @epsilonmajorquezero Agreed, then `findAll` does not work.

Comment: However, you can still use `List<MyObject> findAllByIdIn(List<String> ids)` if you are using Spring data repositories.

Comment: Yeah, but that means then checking for the missing ones "by hand" and I was wondering for a way of doing both things at one if possible.